# Why [active] in <a mat-tab-link > donst work in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material, navbar

```
    <div class="d-flex d-column themed-tab-nav">
            <nav mat-tab-nav-bar color="primary" [tabPanel]="tabPanel" mat-stretch-tabs="false" mat-align-tabs="start">
              <a mat-tab-link  *ngFor="let link of navLinks" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">{{ link.label | translate }}</a>
            </nav>
            <mat-tab-nav-panel #tabPanel>
                <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
            </mat-tab-nav-panel>
        </div>
```

I work with Angular Material and [active] is not working . Why ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem might be that you are not actually setting a `routerLink` for each tab:

```html
<a mat-tab-link  *ngFor="let link of navLinks" 
    [routerLink]="link"
    routerLinkActive 
    #rla="routerLinkActive" 
    [active]="rla.isActive"> {{ link.label | translate }}
</a>
```

This assumes that `link` is a string that represents the route path. [The documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) has a couple of nice examples.

Comment: Nice , but i don't want to can click in nav-bar and navigate to link.path . (I have buttons next and previous for that work )